# Convert the time intervals to equal hours and fill in the value column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data with this structure (YR weather forecasts)

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "time temperature
00 0
01 0
02 1
03 1
04 2
05 2
06 2
07-13 3
13-19 4
19-01 1", header = TRUE)
```

I want to get a structure: each row is one hour, and therefore transform the hourly intervals into the appropriate number of rows

```
> df1.full
   time temperature
1     0           0
2     1           0
3     2           1
4     3           1
5     4           2
6     5           2
7     6           2
8     7           3
9     8           3
10    9           3
11   10           3
12   11           3
13   12           3
14   13           4
15   14           4
16   15           4
17   16           4
18   17           4
19   18           4
20   19           1
21   20           1
22   21           1
23   22           1
24   23           1
```

Comment: Why are you discarding the latter two values from `19-01`? I would assume that since `00` means midnight, that `19-01` should include the next day's midnight and 1am.

Comment: I have the forecast for 00:00 and 01:00 in the next saved file.
March 31 at 20:00 I am saving the file with the forecast for April 1. So I also receive the forecast for April 2 00:00 and April 2 01:00.
When on April 1 at 20:00 I get the forecast, it will include April 2 00:00, 01:00, ... and these will be newer forecasts

Comment: Is there a "date" component to the data? it seems to me that when time rolls over (as it does in your `df1` row 10) that it would be meaningful to increment the day.

Comment: if you have the data in the next file, why is it referenced in this file?

Comment: I don't know why this happens. YR prepares its weather forecasts in this way https://www.yr.no/en/forecast/hourly-table/2-3081368/Poland/Lower%20Silesia/Wroc%C5%82aw/Wroclaw?i=3

The forecast for day 3 covers Wednesday, but the last line moves to Thursday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're discarding things after 11pm, we can do this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # unnest
doseq <- function(z) {
  z <- as.integer(z)
  if (length(z) > 1) {
    if (z[2] < z[1]) z[2] <- 24
    z <- z[1]:max(z[1], z[2]-1)
  }
  z
}

df1 |>
  mutate(time = lapply(strsplit(time, "-"), doseq)) |>
  unnest(time) |>
  print(n=99)
# # A tibble: 24 × 2
#     time temperature
#    <int>       <int>
#  1     0           0
#  2     1           0
#  3     2           1
#  4     3           1
#  5     4           2
#  6     5           2
#  7     6           2
#  8     7           3
#  9     8           3
# 10     9           3
# 11    10           3
# 12    11           3
# 13    12           3
# 14    13           4
# 15    14           4
# 16    15           4
# 17    16           4
# 18    17           4
# 19    18           4
# 20    19           1
# 21    20           1
# 22    21           1
# 23    22           1
# 24    23           1
```

Comment: Thank you. It's almost perfect. Only the time 07:00 disappears

Comment: Right, see my edit @GrBa

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how your real data looks like, but in the case shown, you could `sub` 19-01 to 19-23, then `-` to `:` and `eval`uate the sequences to `cbind`, i.e. sth like

```
> with(df1, 
+      Map(cbind, 
+          lapply(lapply(sub('-', ':', sub('-01', '-23', time)), str2lang), eval), 
+          temperature)) |> do.call(what='rbind')
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    0    0
 [2,]    1    0
 [3,]    2    1
 [4,]    3    1
 [5,]    4    2
 [6,]    5    2
 [7,]    6    2
 [8,]    7    3
 [9,]    8    3
[10,]    9    3
[11,]   10    3
[12,]   11    3
[13,]   12    3
[14,]   13    3
[15,]   13    4
[16,]   14    4
[17,]   15    4
[18,]   16    4
[19,]   17    4
[20,]   18    4
[21,]   19    4
[22,]   19    1
[23,]   20    1
[24,]   21    1
[25,]   22    1
[26,]   23    1
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(time = c("00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", 
"07-13", "13-19", "19-01"), temperature = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```